How to assess differences between tensor product smooths?
Given the following example of a GAM:
data(iris)

library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

mod <- gam(Sepal.Length ~ s(Sepal.Width) + te(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, by = Species),
           data = iris)

draw(mod)


How can be assessed if the tensor product smooths of Petal.Length and Petal.Width significantly differ between Species? It would be interesting to both know if there is a general difference and if yes, for which combinations of Petal.Length and Petal.Width this is true. I am aware that I can plot the difference smooths but I am not sure if I can infer some sort of statistical significance from them?

FYI: your model is missing a parametric effect of Species to model the individual species' mean Sepal.length: add + Species to the formula.


How can be assessed if the tensor product smooths of Petal.Length and
Petal.Width significantly differ between Species?

mod <- gam(Sepal.Length ~ s(Sepal.Width) + te(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, by = Species),
           data = iris)

mod1 <- gam(Sepal.Length ~ s(Sepal.Width) + te(Petal.Length, Petal.Width),
            data = iris)

anova(mod1, mod)
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: Sepal.Length ~ s(Sepal.Width) + te(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
# Model 2: Sepal.Length ~ s(Sepal.Width) + te(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, 
#     by = Species)
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev     Df Deviance      F  Pr(>F)  
# 1    138.73     12.908                                 
# 2    134.46     11.938 4.2743  0.97015 2.5859 0.03635 *
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

They do differ significantly.
I would strongly encourage you to plot the difference between smooths. You could also replace the te smooth with main and interaction smooths (s(x) + s(y) + ti(x, y)) and further investigate in detail.
Since mgcv also provides approximate confidence intervals, you could also check if and where the confidence "bands" (or should I call these volumes?) don't overlap.

Roland's answer takes a model-based analysis of deviance test to test the differences between an interaction and the by-factor interaction, which is probably a correct way of testing the significance of the terms (+1). But based on your question, I assume what you may also be after the actual differences between the tensor product smooths. For this, the gratia package has a nice function called difference_smooths() which estimates this directly by giving the estimate effects and their CIs, along with their plots, like so:
#### Load Libraries ####
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

#### Fit Model ####
mod <- gam(
  Sepal.Length 
  ~ s(Sepal.Width) 
  + te(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, by = Species),
  data = iris
  )

#### Estimate Differences in Smooths ####
diffs <- difference_smooths(
  mod, 
  select = "te(Petal.Length,Petal.Width)",
  group_means = TRUE
  )

#### Draw Differences ####
draw(diffs)

Which gives you this summary:
# A tibble: 30,000 × 10
   .smooth           .by   .level_1 .level_2 .diff   .se .lower_ci .upper_ci
   <chr>             <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.35  3.31     -5.14      7.84
 2 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.33  3.20     -4.95      7.61
 3 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.31  3.09     -4.75      7.38
 4 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.30  2.98     -4.56      7.15
 5 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.28  2.88     -4.36      6.92
 6 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.26  2.77     -4.17      6.69
 7 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.24  2.67     -3.99      6.47
 8 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.23  2.57     -3.80      6.26
 9 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.21  2.47     -3.62      6.05
10 te(Petal.Length,… Spec… setosa   versico…  1.20  2.37     -3.44      5.84

And these plots:


Yes, I know this function. But ideally, the plots would only show the areas where the difference is significant. I could probably assess that based on the confidence intervals? Do you have a suggestion for that?

Not sure if there is a convenient way of doing it, but one way is filtering for CIs that are strictly positive or strictly negative in the diffs object.

@23_ The problem with your suggestion is that you'd have a massive multiple comparisons problem -- by default you'd have 100*100 "tests", one per cell in the surface. We could address that with a simultaneous interval, but that requires a bit more work - the normal credible interval is available but as I said it could be difficult to use reliably. I finish teaching for the semester soon so can take a look at adding simultaneous intervals for difference smooths.

@GavinSimpson Even after handling the multiple comparisons problem, does it actually make sense to plot only regions where a difference is significant? What concerns me is the essentially arbitrary threshold of statistical significance, and the conceptual gulf between "strong evidence of a non-zero difference" and "a difference that is practically meaningful or important". Whatever the problems with NHST, I'd feel pretty comfortable seeing a contour added, say, to indicate regions with p<0.05. Using that contour to exclude non-significant regions from being plotted feels more iffy to me.

@Silverfish Yeah; I wouldn’t just not plot the difference if it weren’t “statistically significant”, but there are other ways to indicate which regions are those where the simultaneous interval excludes 0 difference. One might be to mute the colours (make them transparent say or add another layer where the alpha channel is 1 where the interval excludes 0 and something like 0.2 where 0 is in the interval). Alternatively, a contour would also work. I do think the plot should not plot spaces that are too far from the support of the data, like the plots from draw() do as that is extrapolation

Agree with @Silverfish. in regression models with interactions, the analogous plots are called plots of Johnson-Neyman intervals, and I really dislike them!

Thanks for all your comments. It would be great to have an implementation of some kind in gratia!
